# Extension shortcuts not working in Selenium

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I've created a shortcut to the extension that starts up whenever I press Ctrl+Shift+Z. The shortcut works when I manually use it on the chromedriver browser. I opened a keyboard tracking website that confirms that the keys are being pressed by the selenium script, yet doesn't activate it. If I manually press Ctrl+Shift+Z on my keyboard while the webdriver is open it activates the extension so there's no issue with the extension or webdriver. I'm unsure as to why this is, and I've tried multiple methods

```
driver.get("https://en.key-test.ru/")
actionSteps = ActionChains(driver)
time.sleep(5)
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//body').send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + Keys.SHIFT + 'z') #method 1
driver.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, "body").send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + Keys.SHIFT + "z") #method 2
actionSteps.click.key_down(Keys.CONTROL).key_down(Keys.SHIFT).pause(1).send_keys('Z').key_up(Keys.CONTROL).key_up(Keys.SHIFT).perform() #method 3
```